# Inconsistent failures in Excel VBA for automatic row insert

Tags: vba, excel

I am using an Excel sheet to track my job applications.

I have 2 sheets:
1. first sheet has one row for each application with its latest status
2. second sheet which has each "state" that every application went through eg Completed application -> interview scheduled -> job offered (More likely Completed application -> Application rejected, but I digress).

The vb script that I have does this:
1. On first sheet whenever status of a row is changed, update the timestamp.
2. On second sheet, whenever status of a row is changed in first sheet, create a new row in second sheet with from status ,to status  and timestamp.

#1 works flawlessly. But seemingly at random (most of the time when I update a row in the middle of sheet) the vba crashes with the "end debug" dialog box when inserting row into second sheet

The script is below:

```
Dim oval
Public Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
oval = Target.Value
On Error Resume Next
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub


Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
old_value = oval
Application.EnableEvents = False
If Target.Column = 5 Then
    Cells(Target.Row, 6) = Now
    Dim firstEmptyRow As Long

    Set rngToSearch = Worksheets("Level 2").Range("A:A")
    'Check first cell isn't empty
    If IsEmpty(rngToSearch.Cells(1, 1)) Then
        firstEmptyRow = rngToSearch.Cells(1, 1).Row
    Else
        Set FirstBlankCell = rngToSearch.FindNext(After:=rngToSearch.Cells(1, 1))
        If Not FirstBlankCell Is Nothing Then
            firstEmptyRow = FirstBlankCell.Row
        Else
            'no empty cell in range searched

        End If
    End If
    Debug.Print firstEmptyRow
    Worksheets("Level 2").Cells(firstEmptyRow, 1) = Worksheets("Level 1").Cells(Target.Row, 1)
    Worksheets("Level 2").Cells(firstEmptyRow, 2) = old_value
    Worksheets("Level 2").Cells(firstEmptyRow, 3) = Worksheets("Level 1").Cells(Target.Row, 5)
    Worksheets("Level 2").Cells(firstEmptyRow, 4) = Now

End If
If Target.Column <> 1 And IsEmpty(Worksheets("Level 1").Cells(Target.Row, 1)) Then
    Dim curr_id As Long
    curr_id = Worksheets("Level 1").Cells(Target.Row - 1, 1)
    If Worksheets("Level 1").Cells(Target.Row - 1) = 1 Then
        curr_id = 1
    End If
    Worksheets("Level 1").Cells(Target.Row, 1) = curr_id + 1
End If
On Error Resume Next

Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

I tried a little bit of debugging and here's what I got:
The `firstEmptyRow` value is 0 whenever the vba crashes on the line `Worksheets("Level 2").Cells(firstEmptyRow, 1) = Worksheets("Level 1").Cells(Target.Row, 1)`

This tells me that even thought the range to search is whole A column (which must have an empty row at some point considering I am only into ~200 rows till now) I have not done enough VB programming to figure out how to fix this and I am hoping one of you folks can help me out.

Thanks!

Comment: If you use the VBA debugger, which line does it show that the script fails on?

Comment: It fails on the line `Worksheets("Level 2").Cells(firstEmptyRow, 1) = Worksheets("Level 1").Cells(Target.Row, 1)`

Comment: Look at help for the `Range.Find` method.  I see a `.FindNext` but no `.Find`.  Also, if FirstEmptyRow does not have any non-empty rows below it, you could do something like `FirstEmptyRow = Cells(Rows.Count,"A").end(xlup).Row + 1`

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Thanks! Your second suggestion seems to be working now.